# Angular 2 reset select component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm busy fixing bugs for someone elses Angular 2 code. I have the following modal:

```
    <div class="row">    
         <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="limitClass">Limit Class</label>
                <select class="btn-group form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.limitClass"
                    ngControl="limitClass"  #limitClass="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="onLimitClassSelect($event)"
                    name="limitClass">
                    <option *ngFor="let limitClass of limitClasses" [ngValue]="limitClass.id">
                        {{limitClass.name}}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <div [hidden]="limitClass.valid || limitClass.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                  Limit Class is required
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</modal-content>
<modal-footer>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="close()">Cancel</button>
    <button type="reset" form="form1" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="initializeModal()">Clear</button>
    <button type="submit" form="form1" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</modal-footer>
```

The problem is that when I click the reset button (which clears the form), the "select" item shows the default option (i.e the first option) .

However, if I try and save the form without changing this default option, it crashes with a server error. I need to change the default value in order for the submit to go through. This leads me to believe that while the select option is showing the default value, it's not actually binding to the select object

Is there a way to reset the form, and simultaneously bind the select to the first option?

Sorry if this is unclear, i'll clarify if needed.

Comment: Just make sure that `model.limitClass` is exactly equal (`===`) to the object value of the first option after you clear.

Comment: could you create a plunker? :)